# Составной тип поля для mongodb (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Как для поля в mongoose можно указать составной тип?
Задача следующая: есть два документа "Приход" и "Расход" и при их записи в базу нужно еще делать запись в таблицу с движениями денежных средств, и в этой таблице будет поле "doc" в котором может быть как приход так и расход. Как правильно это делать. Сейчас сделал это так, doc:{id: String, ref: String}, в doc сохраняю id документа и вид, но что то мне кажется что это не правильно:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    kind: String,
    date: Date,
    doc: {
        id: String,
        ref: String
    },
    purse: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Purse'
    },
    article: {
        id: String,
        ref: String,
        name: String
    },
    sum: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('FlowOfFund', schema);
```

Comment: В Mongoose есть enum, но с таким количеством ref'ов стоит переезжать на Postgres. Там enum тоже есть, причём нативный.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать. Это все я делаю для себя, поэтому выбрал mongodb, что бы потренироваться с ней работать.